# Establishing of coefficient unclear

Tags: polynomials

**Exercise**
Determine by inspection the roots of
$$f(x)=3x^3-x^3-10x^2-2x+4=0$$
and, by factorisation, find the rest of the roots.

From the pattern of coefficients it can be seen that $x = −1$ is a solution to the equation.
We therefore write
$$f(x)=(x + 1)(b_3x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0),$$
where
$$b_3 = 3, (b_2 + b_3) = −1, (b_1 + b_2) = −10, (b_0 + b_1) = −2, b_0 = 4.$$
These equations then give $b_3 = 3, b_2 = −4, b_1 = −6, b_0 = 4$, and so
$$f(x)=(x + 1)f_1(x)=(x + 1)(3x^3 − 4x^2 − 6x + 4).$$

**My question**
How do we know the patterns of coefficient in this example? What do I need to know before reading this example?

Comment: The coefficients with odd powers will change sign when you use $x=-1$. If adding all the coefficients you get $0$, then $1$ is root. If you modify the odd ones as described, and add them yields $0$, then $-1$ is a root.

Comment: Did you mean $3x^\color{red}{4}$ on the top line? Lookup the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and [synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division). Hint: you stopped factoring too early.

Comment: @FirstnameLastname if any of the answers met your expectations, please accept it (green button).

Answer (score 1):

*Two polynomials are equal if and only if they have the same degree and corresponding terms have equal coefficients* (in other words, coefficients multiplying equal powers of variable are equal).

Expanding $(x + 1)(b_3x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0)$ gives a polynomial that is equal to $f(x)$
$$b_3x^4 + (b_3+b_2)x^3 + (b_2+b_1)x^2 + (b_1+b_0)x+b_0=3x^3-x^3-10x^2-2x+4.$$
The corresponding system is
\begin{cases}
b_3  =3 \\
b_3+b_2=-1\\
b_2+b_1=-10\\
b_1+b_0=-2\\
b_0=4\end{cases}

Similarly, we find by inspection a root $x=2$ of the polynomial $f_1(x)=3x^3 − 4x^2 − 6x + 4,$ and we can progress analogously.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your answer (and taking for granted that you meant $3x^4-x^3-10x^2-2x+4$, and not $3x^3-x^3-10x^2-2x+4$) the rest can be done as follows:

$(x+1)(3x^3-4x^2-6x+4)$
$=(x+1)(3x^3-6x^2+2x^2-4x-2x+4)$
$=(x+1)[3x^2(x-2)+2x(x-2)-2(x-2)]$
$=(x+1)(x-2)(3x^2+2x-2)$,

where you should stop if you want the factors to be polynomials over the rationals (note that $3x^2+2x-2$ cannot be reduced any further over the rationals). But if you want to allow the factors to be over the reals, not necessarily over the rationals, then you can go one step further to get $(x+1)(x-2)(3x+1+\sqrt{7})(x+\frac{1-\sqrt{7}}{3})$
or perhaps, $(x+1)(x-2)(3x+1-\sqrt{7})(x+\frac{1+\sqrt{7}}{3})$.

Comment: Thank you but what is meant by "pattern of coefficient" ?

Comment: @FirstnameLastname Where did you get the phrase "pattern of the coefficient"? I did not use that in my explanation.

Comment: @FirstnameLastname Do you accept this answer?